# Can I use C++ macro to insert code to different places?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, preprocessor-meta-program

I want to write a macro to both declare a struct field and insert a init process of this field to an `Init()` function. But I find it impossible for a macro to insert code into different places (in this case, field declaration and Init() function definition).

```cpp
// I have 
template <typename T>
T* initValue() {
  // return T* or nullptr
}

// I need some sort of 
DECL_CLASS(MyClass)
DECL_FIELD(int, foo)
DECL_FIELD(float, bar)
DECL_CLASS_END()

// To generate
struct MyClass {
  int *foo;
  float *bar;

public:
  bool Init() {
    if (!(foo = initValue<decay_t<decltype(*foo)>>())) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!(bar = initValue<decay_t<decltype(*bar)>>())) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
};
```

I can use some sort of codegen tools like cog to achieve this, but I don't want to introduce extra syntax into codebase. Can I implement this in pure C++?

If preprocessor can't help in this case, what would you do to make this struct definition simpler?

Comment: Macros cannot do that, in "pure C++".

Comment: If you need only one such class, use an [x-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_macro). If you need multiple classes and want a pretty syntax, use some macro library that can do loops with preprocessor ([here's a lightweight one](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for), or Boost.Preprocessor if you prefer).

Comment: use `std::tuple<int*,float*>`, or more generally `std::tuple<T1,T2,...>` ?

Comment: If you need more powerful code generating capabilities than provided by the core language or the preprocessor, you can use a different mechanism to generate the classes.  In a prior project, we used **Python** to generate a lot of boilerplate classes.  Worked great.  One of the other devs lamented that we should be using the **m4** preprocessor instead, but none of the other devs had any experience with that preprocessor alternative.

Comment: `bool Init` is not C++ style. The default constructor of `MyClass` is `MyClass::MyClass()`, and it fails by throwing an exception. That would make things far more trivial; you just write a single helper function which you use for the default initializers of `foo` and `bar`. Zero macro's needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment, this is how you do it using my [`macro_sequence_for`](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for).

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:30,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:30,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Chttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for/master/include/macro_sequence_for.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0A%23define+DECL_CLASS(name_,+members_)+%5C%0A++++struct+name_+%5C%0A++++%7B+%5C%0A++++++++SF_FOR_EACH(DETAIL_MEMBER_BODY,+SF_NULL,+SF_NULL,,+members_)+%5C%0A++++++public:+%5C%0A++++++++bool+Init()+%5C%0A++++++++%7B+%5C%0A++++++++++++SF_FOR_EACH(DETAIL_MEMBER_INIT,+SF_NULL,+SF_NULL,,+members_)+%5C%0A++++++++++++return+true%3B+%5C%0A++++++++%7D+%5C%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%0A%23define+DETAIL_MEMBER_BODY(n,+d,+name_,+.../*type*/)+%5C%0A++++::std::type_identity_t%3C__VA_ARGS__%3E+*name_+%3D+nullptr%3B%0A%0A%23define+DETAIL_MEMBER_INIT(n,+d,+name_,+.../*type*/)+%5C%0A++++if+(!!(name_+%3D+initValue%3C__VA_ARGS__%3E()))+return+false%3B%0A%0A//+---%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E+T+*initValue()+%7Breturn+new+T%3B%7D%0A%0ADECL_CLASS(+MyClass,%0A++++(foo,+int)%0A++++(bar,+float)%0A)%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:39.97021650820044,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:pp,i:(clang-format:%270%27,editorid:1,filter-headers:%270%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,treeid:0),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Preprocessor+Output+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:40.88756573953618,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1701,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B23+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:37.5,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+17.0.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:19.142217752263388,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

This requires changing the call syntax to:

```
DECL_CLASS( MyClass,
    (foo, int)
    (bar, float)
)
```

Here's the implementation:

```
#include <macro_sequence_for.h>
#include <type_traits>

#define DECL_CLASS(name_, members_) \
    struct name_ \
    { \
        SF_FOR_EACH(DETAIL_MEMBER_BODY, SF_NULL, SF_NULL,, members_) \
      public: \
        bool Init() \
        { \
            SF_FOR_EACH(DETAIL_MEMBER_INIT, SF_NULL, SF_NULL,, members_) \
            return true; \
        } \
    };

#define DETAIL_MEMBER_BODY(n, d, name_, .../*type*/) \
    ::std::type_identity_t<__VA_ARGS__> *name_ = nullptr;

#define DETAIL_MEMBER_INIT(n, d, name_, .../*type*/) \
    if (!(name_ = initValue<__VA_ARGS__>())) return false;
```

This expands to:

```
struct MyClass
{
    ::std::type_identity_t<int> *foo = nullptr;
    ::std::type_identity_t<float> *bar = nullptr;

  public:
    bool Init()
    {
        if (!(foo = initValue<int>()))
            return false;
        if (!(bar = initValue<float>()))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
};
```

Note the use of `std::type_identity_t`. This lets it work with e.g. arrays, since e.g. `int[4] *foo;` is invalid, but `type_identity_t<int[4]> *foo;` is fine.

Note `(name, type)` instead of `(type, name)` (and using `...` for the type). This lets you use types with commas in their names, such as `std::map<X, Y>`.

And here's the same thing without my library:

```
#define DECL_CLASS(name_, members_) \
    struct name_ \
    { \
        END(MEMBER_A members_) \
      public: \
        bool Init() \
        { \
            END(INIT_A members_) \
            return true; \
        } \
    };

#define END(...) END_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define END_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_END

#define MEMBER_A(...) MEMBER_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) MEMBER_B
#define MEMBER_B(...) MEMBER_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) MEMBER_A
#define MEMBER_A_END
#define MEMBER_B_END

#define MEMBER_BODY(name_, .../*type*/) \
    ::std::type_identity_t<__VA_ARGS__> *name_ = nullptr;

#define INIT_A(...) INIT_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) INIT_B
#define INIT_B(...) INIT_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) INIT_A
#define INIT_A_END
#define INIT_B_END

#define INIT_BODY(name_, .../*type*/) \
    if (!(name_ = initValue<__VA_ARGS__>())) return false;
```

Comment: Thanks! Impressed by this MEMBER_A MEMBER_B pattern!
For those who would like to see a Boost.Preprocessor implementation
https://godbolt.org/z/4oKv3Ko51

Comment: @osennyaya Yep! The issue with this A/B pattern is that it doesn't let you pass external information into the loop body (luckily you didn't need it here). Boost.PP can do that, but it has a hardcoded limit on the number of iterations, I think (probably not a big deal in practice though).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to construct a lot of these kinds of objects, this can be achieved by using this little trick (C++17).

```
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
T* init_value();

#define DECL_CLASS(NAME) \
    struct NAME { \
        using self_type = NAME; \
        using my_init_function = bool(*)(NAME*); \
        static inline std::vector<my_init_function> my_init_functions;

#define DECL_CLASS_END() \
    public: \
    bool Init() { \
        for (auto init_func : my_init_functions) { \
            if (!init_func(this)) \
                return false; \
        } \
        return true; \
    } \
    };

#define DECL_FIELD(TYPE, NAME) \
    TYPE* NAME = []() { \
        static std::once_flag reg_flag; \
        std::call_once(reg_flag, []() { \
            my_init_functions.push_back([](self_type* self) -> bool { \
                self->NAME = init_value<TYPE>(); \
                return self->NAME != nullptr; \
            }); \
        }); \
        return nullptr; \
    }();

DECL_CLASS(MyClass)
DECL_FIELD(int, foo)
DECL_FIELD(float, bar)
DECL_FIELD(bool, baz)
DECL_CLASS_END()
```

If we try this out using this program

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T* init_value() {
    if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
        std::cout << "Initialized int\n";
    else if (std::is_same<T, float>::value)
        std::cout << "Initialized float\n";
    else if (std::is_same<T, bool>::value)
        // Pretend we don't know how to initialize bools
        return nullptr;
    else
        std::cout << "Initialized other\n";

    return new T; // Ignoring leak for now, don't do this at home.
}

int main()
{
    MyClass c;
    std::cout << "MyClass constructed\n";
    auto ok = c.Init();
    if (!ok)
        std::cout << "Failed initialization\n";
    
    MyClass c2;
    std::cout << "MyClass constructed\n";
    ok = c2.Init();
    if (!ok)
        std::cout << "Failed initialization\n";
}
```

we will see that it prints

```
MyClass constructed
Initialized int
Initialized float
Failed initialization
MyClass constructed
Initialized int
Initialized float
Failed initialization
```

This works by registering a type-erased initialization callback to a static class vector which we can iterate over.
Since we only want to register the initialization callbacks one time, we have to use `std::call_once` every time we construct one of these objects. If the performance impact of this is acceptable then everything is fine. Otherwise this will not be sufficient and other measures must be taken.